# (tryMS) in ajax HttpRequest

Tags: javascript, ajax

In the follow ajax request could some one please explain (tryMS)

```
function createRequest() {
  try {
    request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } catch (tryMS) {
    try {
      request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (otherMS) {
      try {
        request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      } catch (failed) {
        request = null;
      }
    }
  } 
  return request;
}
```

Is (tryMS), and (otherMS) part of javascript or is it just a common argument used in the code, do they have specific functions? If its an argument wheres it value coming from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, `tryMS` and `otherMS` are just variable names. You could replace them with any valid variable name and the logic would be exactly the same. In this case, the object they will represent at runtime is a subclass of `Exception` as they are used in the catch clause of  a try-catch statement.

You can read more about [try-catch-finally here.](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/trycatch.shtml)

I wouldn't agree with the naming convention being used here, but the variable name is essentially describing the flow of control based on the browser being used. For example, if the creation of an `XMLHttpRequest` object causes an exception to be raised, then we should try an AJAX technique for microsoft browsers using `ActiveXObject` - hence the name `tryMS`.

Comment: Thank you! Ive been searching for an hr trying to find something online explaining the setup

Answer (score 1):

Internet Explorer doesn't have an xhr `XmlHttpRequest` -- they have their own object for that.  This code is trying to be browser agnostic; i.e. trying to work no matter the browser.  The `createRequest` method tries to create an `XMLHttpRequest`.  If that fails, it tries to create the first `ActiveXObject`.  If that fails, it falls back to the next active x object.

> Is (tryMS), and (otherMS) part of javascript or is it just a common
>   argument used in the code, do they have specific functions? If its an
>   argument wheres it value coming from.

`try/catch` statements pass the error to to the catch block.  So `tryMS` and `otherMS` and `failed` are all just references to a string that describes the error.

Comment: I think the question is about the try/catch construct, rather than AJAX.